# Splitting text by newline character "\n" in Adobe AIR

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, file-io, air

I am creating a AIR application in flex. I have a textArea having a string something like -

```
AAA BBB CCC DDD
QQQ WWW EEE SSS
KKPPP SSSL AAAS
```

I want this to save this into .txt file.

I am using -

```
file.save(output.text,"testFile.txt");
```

But its is saving everything in 1 line. When I open the file using notepad everything is coming as Single line.

Does flex provide any functionality using which I can save the contents of multiline Text Area into .txt file?

The output string has got the '\n' but notepad is not able to recognize it. Is it a Flex issue or Windows notepad issue? If it is notepad issue then is there any way to work around this from Flex file io?

Please help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notepad is the culprit - it only understands `\r\n` newlines (the *Windows newlines*).

Open the file in wordpad or [notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/) and you can see the text in multiple lines.

If you want to support notepad too, you can replace `\n` with `\r\n` before writing it to the file - smart editors will convert them to single `\n` before displaying it:

```
file.save(output.text.replace("\n", "\r\n"), "testFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't get into that jungle, you are not going to get it right. Take a look to [`File.lineEnding`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html?allClasses=1#lineEnding) and let Adobe deal with it.

Comment: This is also very useful. Thanks alot :)